# Appending a list into another list. 'str' object has no attribute 'append' Error occurs

Tags: python, list, append, nested-lists

I created a list grapsedParts:

```
graspedParts = []

pickInfo = [robo.ActiveTool, part]

graspedParts.append(pickInfo)
```

but for some reason it treats the graspedParts as a String and not a list. It keeps returning

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

I have google the error and understood that one cant append to a str but I cant see where I go wrong. Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: You're surely redifining `graspedParts` as a string at some intermediate point

Comment: The issue was that I declared it as a global and initialized it elsewhere. Thanks for the help regardless.
Edit: That shouldn't have been a issue actually, I tried running it again as I had it above and its worked now for some reason. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Try changing graspedParts to be a list, i.e.,

```
graspedParts = list()
```

Comment: ``[]`` and ``list()`` are equivalent, barring some implementation specific optimisations that do not change the result.